# phpmyadmin not working on windows10

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed xampp on my windows10 machine.
All the php and html files run perfectly by being placed in **drive:\xampp\htdocs**
folder but when i placed **phpmyadmin extracted folder** in **\htdocs** the **http://localhost/phpmyadmin/** doesn't work and i get an access forbidden message.

However, when i place **phpmyadmin** in **drive:/xampp** then **http://localhost/phpmyadmin**
works perfectly .
I don't understand this every tutorial my friends and everywhere phpmyadmin works by placing in **/xampp/htdocs** directory but mine is working by placing in /xampp.
Anyone could help..?

Comment: Have you looked at the configuration files for Apache to see where it expects phpMyAdmin to be?

Comment: Try to install xampp in C://

Comment: The root directory for xampp is set to drive:/xampp/htdocs so i guess that's where phphmyadmin should be..@JayBlanchard

Comment: No, go look at the Apache config files and it will tell you where Apache expects phpMyAdmin to be.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard you were right.The updated xampp by default uses /xampp for phpmyadmin alias. Thanks problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is a normal configuration that phpmyadmin is not in the website document root (`xampp/htdocs`). The website document root is for the user website files, while phpmyadmin is part of xampp, and gets installed in the `xampp` directory. 
Look at the Apache configuration files for more details.

Comment: When i open apache->config->phpmyadmin(config.inc.php) it is an empty file.However,phpmyadmin directory has a configured config.inc.php.